# A usage of the word "by"

Tags: word-usage, phrase-usage

In a scenario, we have 15 people in the team. We are requested to split into 3 groups(each has 5) to make the reporting.

By looking up a dictionary, the word "by" can mean:

> used to show what unit of measurement or quantity is involved in selling, paying for, producing etc. something

For example, we are paid by the hour.

Similarly, can we use "by the group" to describe the idea above? Like:

> We are requested to make the reporting by the group.

It doesn't seem right because "the group" sounds more like the specific group rather as a unit.

What would be the correct way(or the correct usage of by) to express it here, if it's not correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic idea of using "by" is correct in your sample sentence. To ***report by group*** means that each group should do its own reporting separately from one another.

The sentence, however, has other grammatical issues. A person or people (***we***) cannot be ***requested*** directly in the sense you use it. You can request someone, but it's awkward to request someone *to do something*. Also, it is probably better to say ***to report*** instead of ***make the reporting***, because "make" is not normally used with "reporting." So the final sentence could look like this:

> ***It is requested that we report by group.***

Or:

> ***The teacher requested that we report by group.***

Comment: I wonder why "by the hour", "by group" (not by the group)? Also, someone suggested me "report in small groups". Is that correct too?

Comment: Also, I saw a sentence in a dict: "All club members are requested to attend the annual meeting."

Comment: I searched on the web regarding "do a report" vs "make a report". Someone gives answer:"I have just given a simple answer to one of my ESL learners, and that is that generally speaking "Making a report" would have a verbal/ face to face connotation and "Doing a report" would have a written connotation. " . What's your opinion for this? Seems many questions here. :)

Comment: I think ***by the hour*** because you use the article "the" with periods of time. Anyway, there are web pages that describe all the cases of when to use the definite article "the." ***Report in small groups*** is fine.

Comment: Yes, "make a report" may have that connotation -- similar to "give a report" in class. It is, however, just a connotation. You can spend two weeks "making a report" on your computer.

Comment: You may want to say "make a report by group" instead of "report by group." Obviously they have different meanings. I was just trying to say "make a report*ing* by group" is awkward.

Comment: But "do a reporting" sounds natural?

Comment: No, "make a reporting" and "do a reporting" both sound awkward. There is no verb that works well in this case.

Comment: But you actually said "... ...do its own reporting separately from one another"

Comment: ***Do your own reporting*** or ***do the reporting of a professional*** are common phrases. They refer to distinct, definite, specific actions. ***Do a reporting*** uses the article "a," which is not **definite**. In this particular case, people just don't use the phrase with "a." I understand that this can be difficult to grasp. This page is a good primer on the differences between "the" and "a": http://www.ef.edu/english-resources/english-grammar/definite-article/

Comment: To wrap it up, these are correct: do a report, make a report, do the reporting. these are not: make the reporting, do a reporting. Am I getting them right or you have more to add?

Comment: Yes, that's a good summary...

Comment: It's worth noting that you can say ***do the XXXing*** with any verb. You can read more about *gerunds* here: http://www.ef.edu/english-resources/english-grammar/gerund/

Comment: is "do the report" correct?

Comment: yes, "do the report" is very commonly used.